# Meaning of the green color bar from Android GPU/HWUI Rendering Profiler

Tags: android, android-profiler, hwui

[image]

This is the screenshot of Profile HWUI Rendering of my app. As you can see the marked section in the screenshot, it is a lime green color bar. I tried to figure out the meaning of this color at the documentation here (https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/inspect-gpu-rendering). However, there is no lime green in the documentation as shown below.

[image]

So anyone know what does this lime green bar mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a documentation bug so the team just updated the color legends. Please take a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/inspect-gpu-rendering and see if it makes more sense now.